# C++ angles, trigonometry

Tags: c++, trigonometry, angle

I need some help calculating angles of points:
[image]

I need to calculate angle from point (0,0) to points extracted from image. 1 would be 0*, 2 is about 40-44* etc.

My problem is that atan2 shows incorrect values. 
Current output of atan2 is:

```
 1:41.867535 2:64.653824 3:52.915009 4:30.375608 5:13.328092
```

How can I calculate it from point 0,0? I can't use any non-standard libraries.

I'm still doing something wrong. I'm trying:

```
   arrow1 = (M_PI - atan2(y, x) * (180 / M_PI);
```

Output:

```
   1: 131.867538  2: 154.653824  3: 142.915009  4: 120.375610  5: 103.328094
```

And:

```
   arrow1 = (M_PI - atan2(y, -x) * (180 / M_PI);
```

Output:

```
    1: 48.132465  2: 25.346176  3: 37.084991  4: 59.624393  5: 76.671906
```

Comment: Please show your code so that we can help you figure it out.

Comment: The existing code is working ok (finding parts of image etc. is ok). My problem is lack of the code for counting angles. Output is from simple: arrow1 = atan2(x,y) *180 / M_PI;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angle returned from `atan2(deltaY, deltaX)` will be the angle, in radians, counter clockwise from the X axis.

You are currently using  `arrow1 = atan2(x,y) *180 / M_PI;`, so you need to convert that to using `(y,x)`, then also switch so you're taking the angle clockwise from -X instead of CCW from +X.

This means the angle for point 1, if you feed it as `atan2(-1, 0)`, will be 180 degrees.  To achieve the angle you wish, it should be:

```
double angleFromX = atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
double angle = M_PI - angleFromX;
double angleInDegrees = 180 * angle / M_PI;
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to add checks against `x==0`.